# What's wrong with this file renaming loop?

Tags: bash, loops, redirect, pipe

I'm trying to iterate through all the files in a directory and rename them from the prefix ABC to XYZ using the command below

```
while read file; do mv \"$file\" \"$(echo $file | sed -e s/ABC/XYZ/g)\" ; done < <(ls -1)
```

When I throw an echo in front of the `mv`, everything looks like it should work fine and copy/pasting the outputted command works fine but it won't execute correctly within the context of the loop giving me a usage error as if the command is malformed like below.

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Even though the outputted command from the check with echo gives

```
mv "ABC Test1" "XYZ Test1"
```

which should be a valid command and works if I copy paste.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I tested here with `while read file; do 
      mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e s/ABC/XYZ/g) ; 
done < <(ls -1)` and it worked... What is the message you are getting?

Comment: See below. The escaped quotes produced correct echo output but did not have the intended functionality in mv. Removing the escapes fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relace:

```
while read file; do mv \"$file\" \"$(echo $file | sed -e s/ABC/XYZ/g)\" ; done < <(ls -1)
```

With:

```
for file in *
do
    mv "$file" "${file//ABC/XYZ}"
done
```

Notes:

1. This is very important: [Never parse `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls` is only designed to produce human-friendly output.
2. To iterate over all files in a directory, use `for file in *; do ...; done`.  This will work reliably for all manor of file names including file names with newlines, blanks, or other difficult characters.
3. `\"` produces a literal character, not a syntactic character.  Since we want the syntactic meaning of `"` here, we leave it unescaped.
4. There are times when one needs `sed` but this isn't one of them. 
   The shell is capable of doing simple substitutions without all the issues associated with command substitution.  Thus, `$(echo $file | sed -e s/ABC/XYZ/g)` can be replaced with `${file//ABC/XYZ}`.

   The form `${var//old/new}` is called *pattern substitution* and is documented in `man bash`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The * is probably better than using `ls -1` but do they not have the same intended effect if `ls -1` is parsed by line with read? Also what is the technical name for `${}`? I'd like to read on it

Comment: `ls`'s output can be ambiguous an/or can confuse `read` if your filenames contain any of a number of special characters (which are perfectly legal in filenames). `*` just doesn't have this problem at all. BTW, using `echo` is a generally bad way to find out what command will be executed, because it prints only literal quotes and escapes, but not syntactic quotes and escapes; this can be very misleading (as you've seen).

Comment: @snowman4839 As just one example, it is perfectly for file names to include newlines.  Consequently, looping over `ls -1` can lead to problems.  For more, see [this excellent discussion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Separately, `${var//old/new}` is called _pattern substitution_  and is documented in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Very stupid mistake. There was no need to escape the quotes in the mv command. Taking those out makes it work as expected. Escaping the quotes shows the correct output with echo but does not give intended behavior.

`while read file; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e s/ABC/XYZ/g)" ; done < <(ls -1)`